# Empty response from springboot server with token keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, authentication, keycloak

I have a Springboot server and a keycloak server, if I get the token from keycloak and I give it to Springboot it gives to me a response but EMPTY!

These are my configurations:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class KeycloakSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }


}
```

Here the properties:

```
keycloak.realm=***
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=***
keycloak.credentials.secret=***
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings=true
keycloak.bearer-only=true
```

This is the result obtained from postman:

[image]

Comment: The token is only that size? or did you altered ?

Comment: the token is complete  isn't visible in the UI!

Comment: That token that you posted in the postman is not complete, are you copying the entire token correctly ? Can you add the code from which you are actually extracting the token?

Comment: yes the token is complete

Comment: How are you requesting the token?